# replace rows from one csv file to another csv where id of is the samePHP?

Tags: php, csv

I have one excel  orginal.csv file

```
ID     Name     Price
1      Xblue      12
2      Yblue      32
3      Zblue      52
```

And another copy.csv file

```
ID     Name     Price
1      Xblue      89
2      Yblue      43
3      Zblue      45
```

I want to replace rows from orginal.csv to copy.csv where ID is the same. 
Can I do this manually or maybe somehow using PHP?

I search for some options on the internet, but I only found getcsv and readcsv functions that can't help me in this case. Cause this is something like updating CSV file.

Comment: You need to get CSV data from both the files then you can use a loop to update data.

Comment: do you have some code example?

Answer (score 0):

It may end up in request timeout in PHP because it requires so many loops to do it. If someone can reduce the time complexity of this program then it will work. if it even works it will take a lot of time to do it.

```
while(! feof($f_pointer)){ //open old csv to update loop1
$ar=fgetcsv($f_pointer);  // getting first row

for($i=0;$i<count($ar);$i++){ //loop2 first row array
 $f_pointer2=fopen("new.csv","r"); open new csv to get data
while(! feof($f_pointer2)){    // loop3 to find ID in new csv
$ar2=fgetcsv($f_pointer2);    //getting each row in array
for($j=0;$j<count($ar2);$j++){   //loop4 to compare id of old csv to new csv and update data

if($ar[i] == $ar2[j]){  
foreach ($ar2 as $fields) {   //loop5
fputcsv($f_pointer, $fields);
      }

    } 
   } 
  } 
 } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: can somehow made condition to replace rows who have same IDS?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a little soulution. If order is important you don't have to index the array and loop through the copied array.

```
<?php
if(file_exists('output.csv'))
{
    unlink('output.csv');
}

function fputcsv_eol($handle, $array, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"', $eol = "\n") {
    $return = fputcsv($handle, $array, $delimiter, $enclosure);
    if($return !== FALSE && "\n" != $eol && 0 === fseek($handle, -1, SEEK_CUR)) {
        fwrite($handle, $eol);
    }
    return $return;
}

function scanFile($sFilename, $iIndexColumn)
{
    $rFile = fopen($sFilename, 'r');
    $aData = array();

    while(($aLine = fgetcsv($rFile)) !== false)
    {
        $aData[$aLine[$iIndexColumn]] = $aLine;
    }
    fclose($rFile);
    return $aData;
}

$iIndexColumn = 0;
$iValueColum = 2;

$aOriginalData = scanFile('original.csv', 0);
$aCopyData = scanFile('copy.csv', 0);

foreach($aOriginalData as $iID => $aOriginalDatum)
{
    if(array_key_exists($iID, $aCopyData))
    {
        $aCopyData[$iID] = $aOriginalDatum;
    }
}

$rFile = fopen('output.csv', 'w');
foreach($aCopyData as $aCopyDatum)
{
    fputcsv_eol($rFile, $aCopyDatum, ',', '"',"\r\n");
}

fclose($rFile);
```

Comment: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given

Comment: I'm only mobile at the moment. I think I've fixed it. I'll come back tomorrow to test it probably.

Comment: @doki the example files (changed the separator in the file to ",")  are correctly interpreted

Comment: this code is still not good, it put all values in one row horizontally?

Comment: @doki There could be a problem with the lineending (unix-default: \r). You can read your current file with e.g. Notepad++ or pspad. I've updated my code to export the file with windows style endings ('\r\n'). Try it again

Comment: still not looks good on excel, on notepad is good, but i need this in excel ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183734/discussion-between-finder2-and-doki).